# UWP remove size slider from inkToolbarPenButton

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

I am trying to make an [InkToolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inktoolbar?view=winrt-18362) whose ballpens and pencils' size can't be changed. Basically, the actual appearance is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vugcl.png) (the button has a slider with a "size" text) and I want to remove it so it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLbRE.png), without that slider. I've read the whole [tutorial about custom ink toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/ink-toolbar), but I haven't been able to find the property that I want to remove. In fact, I'm not sure if I can do so.
Is there any way to prevent users from seeing and using this size property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom `InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl` located in `Generic.xaml` in your pc.

For details.

Step 1, open `Generic.xaml`, find text `<Style TargetType="InkToolbarPenConfigurationControl">`, copy out the whole Style, you can also see on [my gist](https://gist.github.com/hupo376787/2faa8eefe2f5fa668f593850160f6306).

Step 2, paste the style code to your `App.xaml`. Note this will override all your `InkToolbarPen` button.

```
<Application
    x:Class="App2.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FavoriteButtonStyle.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/BorderlessGridViewItem.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


            <!--Paste your style code here-->

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Step 3, find the `Slider` control, set `Visibility` to `Collapsed`. Done!!!

[image]